# Convert string to SQL Server uniqueidentifier in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Is there any built-in method in asp.net to convert a string to a `uniqueidentifier` for SQL Server, just like `.ToString()`.

I get an error: `Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.`

Or does anyone have an idea how to do solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have a field called ` @RoleID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` in database.I want to send a value through asp.net which is string.If i avoid this column every things is ok.If pass the value i got the above error.Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a constructor for `Guid` which takes a `string` as a parameter.

```
Guid aGuid = new Guid(aString);
```

Make sure it's in the correct format:

> A string that contains a GUID in one of the following formats ("d"
>   represents a hexadecimal digit whose case is ignored):
>
> 32 contiguous digits: dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
>
> -or-
>
> Groups of 8, 4, 4, 4, and 12 digits with hyphens between the groups. The entire GUID can optionally be enclosed in matching braces
>   or parentheses: dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd -or- {dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd} -or- (dddddddd-dddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddddddd)
>
> -or-
>
> Groups of 8, 4, and 4 digits, and a subset of eight groups of 2 digits, with each group prefixed by "0x" or "0X", and separated by
>   commas. The entire GUID, as well as the subset, is enclosed in
>   matching braces: {0xdddddddd, 0xdddd,
>   0xdddd,{0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd,0xdd}}

Full documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library./96ff78dc.aspx).

You can pass your RoleID guid in as a parameter:

```
Guid roleID = new Guid(roleIDAsString);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@RoleID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = roleID;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Guid outGuid;
Guid.TryParse(stringInput, out outGuid);
```

Won't crash if the string is incorrectly formatted

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 Guid myNew = new Guid("xxxx-xxx");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string aspUserID = myObject.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
Guid userGuid = new Guid(aspUserID);
```

or

```
 Guid yourGuid = new Guid(yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the string value before using it

```
Guid g = new Guid(string) ;
```